# PHP objects with Int variables

Tags: php, object

I've noticed something quite strange with PHP Objects and can't find a documented cause of it.

The following code demonstrates the behaviour

```
<?php
$a = (object) array( 0 => 1 );
foreach($a as $b => $c) {
  $a->$b = ++$c;  //I'm expecting the key to be overwritten here
}
var_dump($a);
$var = 0;
var_dump($a->$var);
$var = "0";
var_dump($a->$var);
```

and the output

```
object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  ["0"]=>
  int(2)
}
int(2)
int(2)
```

Is the numeric part of the class inaccessible using `->` syntax?

Comment: As an answer. Yes, it is inaccessible using ->. But the why and knowhow, I have no idea, good question!

Comment: `key to be overwritten here` do you want `$a->1` instead of `$a->0`

Comment: I want `$a` to contain 1 variable, not 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you perform an `(object)` cast on an array you promote that array as the *internal* property list of an anonymous object (i.e. stdClass).

The way properties are indexed in an object is slightly different than that of an array; specifically, object property names are always treated as strings whereas array indices are looked up based on the intended type (e.g. numeric strings are seen as integers).

The above behaviour doesn't affect `foreach` loops because there's no hashing involved there; as far as PHP is concerned, a regular array is being iterated.

To answer your question, yes, the numeric keys from your original array can't be accessed using the `->` operator. To avoid this you should remove the numeric indices from your array before the cast is performed.

It's hard to find this behaviour in the documentation, but a hint of it can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting):

> If an object is converted to an array, the result is an array whose elements are the object's properties. The keys are the member variable names, with a few notable exceptions: integer properties are unaccessible ...

#### FYI

In this particular case you can circumvent the issue by using references; this is not recommended, please follow the earlier advise of not using numeric property names:

```
foreach ($a as &$c) {
    ++$c;
}
unset($c);
```

#### Update

2014-11-26: I've updated the documentation; the live pages will be updated this Friday - [commit](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/phpdoc/en/trunk/language/types/object.xml?r1=288721&r2=335216).

Comment: Why does the cast not re index the properties to be strings ? Is this documented ?

Comment: I know i can use the pass by ref, The code was used to demonstrate the issue, rather that being used code.

Comment: `var_dump((array) ((object) array( 0 => 1 )));` shows the item, which it shouldn't according to the docs ?

Comment: @exussum `var_dump()` is a debugging tool .. it doesn't highlight the underlying issue in this case, because internally it uses a `foreach` to iterate over the properties, just like you do.

Comment: Its saying the keys are gone, even if `$a = (array) $a; echo $a[0]` works when the docs suggest it should not

Comment: @exussum it says numeric properties are unaccessible, which is true (because of hashing algorithm mismatch) ... casting a "broken" object back into an array will yield the array you started with AFAICT.

Comment: Im not so sure, because without doing the initial cast it seems there is no way to make a numeric property ?

Comment: @exussum You can do `$obj->{'5'} = 'foo';`, but that doesn't make it truly numeric ... it's stored under a string key.

Comment: But that still means the docs are incorrect, that results in a key of string "5" which is accessible

Comment: @exussum I've updated the manual to reflect the changes [here](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/phpdoc/en/trunk/language/types/object.xml?r1=288721&r2=335216); let me know if you still have questions.

Answer (score 1):

`stdClass` handles data terribly loosely, since it's an object representation of an internal array (thus the ability of of casting without problems).

```
$stdClassObject->property = "value";
```

The property is handled as a string, but upon casting, the property type doesn't change (which is somehow understandable, as if you cast to an object and then to an array again, you'd have lost all the integer indexes).

I don't think they could do better than that, but you can create your own alternative to stdClass :-)